# Installed python-telegram-bot but still showing "No module named 'telegram'"

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Hi I already installed Python-telegram-bot using pip install python-telegram-bot. However, when i run my python file in VS, it shows "No module named 'telegram'. I confirmed that i only have 1 version of python installed 3.8.3 and still unable to find any solution.

I have anaconda installed as well, and i am not sure if it is the cause to this issue.

The error is prompted in the line below:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
```

Comment: make sure that you're running your script on the same python version and in the same virtual environment where you installed ptb. Please keep in mind that issues with package management are not specific to ptb, but a general python topic.

Answer (score 0):

After installing python-telegram-bot, you should use telegram.ext for all functions you want to use for example

```python
Telegram.ext.CommanHandler()
Telegram.ext.MessageHandler(Telegram.ext.Filter.text,function-name)
```

We use that because we have to show the address for Telegram.ext function